# Computing a canonical module

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a complete local Noetherian $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra with maximal ideal $m$ and residue field $k = R/m$. Assume $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay and there is a ring homomorphism $S \to R$ which makes $R$ a finitely-generated free $S$-module, where $S$ is a power series ring over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with $\dim S = \dim R$. I want to show that the canonical module $\omega_R$ of $R$ is isomorphic to $\textrm{Hom}_S(R,S)$ (with $R$-module structure given by $(r \cdot \varphi)(x) = \varphi(rx)$ for $r,x \in R, \varphi \in \textrm{Hom}_S(R,S))$.

This should amount to showing that $\dim_k \textrm{Ext}^i_R(k,\textrm{Hom}_S(R,S))$ is equal to $1$ if $i = \dim R$ and $0$ otherwise. We can take a free resolution
$$\cdots \to R^n \to R \to k \to 0$$
of $k$ and take the cochain complex
$$0 \to \textrm{Hom}_R(R, \textrm{Hom}_S(R,S)) \to \textrm{Hom}_R(R^n, \textrm{Hom}_S(R,S)) \to \cdots.$$
Now
$$\textrm{Hom}_R(R^n, \textrm{Hom}_S(R,S)) \cong \textrm{Hom}_S(R,S)^n,$$
but I don't see where to proceed from here. For context I am trying to verify the first sentence in the proof of Lemma 3.9 in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.09729.pdf.

Comment: You need to assume something about $S$ for this to be true. In practice, $S$ is typically a Noether normalization or is at least Gorenstein. Indeed, otherwise you could just take $S=R$ and it would satisfy your hypotheses, but $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,R) \cong R$ is the canonical module of $R$ if and only if $R$ is Gorenstein.

Comment: I'm fine with assuming $S$ is a regular local ring (in fact a power series ring over let's say $\mathbb{Z}_p$) I wasn't exactly sure what the assumptions on $S$ needed to be as the paper only mentions that $R$ is free over $S$. I've edited the question\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we have the following

> Theorem [See Theorem 3.3.7 (b) [here ]](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cohenmacaulay-rings/938BC2204D8A7C99E2CEBA1695A692A4) If $S \to R$ is a finite local map of local Cohen-Macaulay rings such that $S$ admits a canonical module $\omega_S$, then $R$ admits a canonical module $\omega_R$ and $\omega_R \cong \operatorname{Ext}_S^{\dim S-\dim R}(R,\omega_S)$.

In your setting, $S$ is regular (in particular Gorenstein) so $\omega_S \cong S$ and we also have $\dim S=\dim R$, so the above result gives $\omega_R \cong \operatorname{Hom}_S(R,S)$.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!